# Building a menu in Android

Tags: android, menu

I'm writing an Android application that needs a menu like this:

[image]

Please note, this activity has a background and 4 menu items, where each menu item has two parts: Bottom text that should be aligned to left and Right text that should be aligned to right. Would you please tell me how I can implement it? Should I use `LinearLayout` for each menu item?

Comment: Do you have a specific question or do you want people here to write the code for you? If the question is 'can a Linear Layout be used to achieve a screen like this one?' then yes because all the elements are situated linearly. Relative Layout might be a more universal option though.

Comment: Actually LinearLayout was my first idea. But I'm a little afraid of OutOfMemory exception, when the number of menu Items increases. So I'm looking for new ideas. And some lines of codes would be prefect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample code I made. all of them are buttons in xml

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
// My menu inflater
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

// code for the actions that it will do.
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.test2:
    test2();
    return true;
case R.id.test1:
    test1();
    return true;
default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}

 public void test1() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast test = Toast.makeText(this, "This is a test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
test.show();
 }

 public void test2() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast test = Toast.makeText(this, "This is a test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
test.show();
  //Add how ever many you want. 
 }
}
```